# Image uploads not working - Imgur rejecting request, on multiple sites

Tags: support, status-completed, images, imgur, uploader

So far I've tested Ask Ubuntu, StackOverflow, and others, and others in TL have tested other sites and we're getting upload rejected failures for image uploads to imgur, even if the image size is very small and acceptable.

It seems like this would be an issue on Imgur's end, but I want to rule out any SE-wide issue; can someone see if this is an SE-side issue or if it's Imgur's fault?

Comment: Imgur has been having intermittent server load problems today. I had trouble accessing images earlier.

Comment: So it's on Imgur's side, and is an intermittent, transient issue.  That makes sense, actually, thank you for the note, @animuson.

Comment: I found this issue mainly in chat uploader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** With the help of Imgur it appears to be resolved at least on my end.  If you find you are still having an issue please let me know.

I have raised an issue with our contacts at Imgur to help us resolve this issue.  It appears to be very intermittent as reported and we are aware and working on getting this fixed.

Comment: Seems to be working now.  Thank you for your prompt response and handling this!

Comment: Another error [Server Error: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420821/server-error-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-server).